# Why is my scoped service being called as a new instance every time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, scope

This is a practice ASP.NET project I'm using to better understand a few techniques, and while I've got Dependency Injection working, its not working quite as I want it to. I have a class that I want to use to store a history, so every time the user hits a submit button, it displays a result, and after the second time it starts displaying the history. Anyway I added the history to the DI as a scoped service, thinking that would mean it would be created and then remain the same instance for the duration of the session for that user. However according to the debugger it looks like the list never gets bigger than one, and thats at the point of adding the item to the list. So the code.

The object

```
{
    public class RollHistory : IRollHistory
    {
        public List<IRollMessage> Entries { get; set; } = new List<IRollMessage>();
    }
}
```

The DI

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddTransient<IDiceTray, DiceTray>();
            services.AddTransient<IRollMessage, RollMessage>();
            services.AddScoped<IRollHistory, RollHistory>();
        }
```

The Controller constructor

```
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IDiceTray diceTray, IRollMessage rollMessage, IRollHistory rollHistory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _diceTray = diceTray;
        _rollMessage = rollMessage;
        _rollHistory = rollHistory;
    }
```

And the code for when the button gets clicked

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(DiceRollModel diceRoll)
    {
        _diceTray.DiceRoll(diceRoll.DiceType, diceRoll.DiceCount, diceRoll.Bonus, diceRoll.VantageType);
        _rollMessage.RollMessages(_diceTray);
        diceRoll.RollResult = _rollMessage;
        _rollHistory.Entries.Add(_rollMessage);
        diceRoll.History = _rollHistory.Entries;
        return View(diceRoll);
    }
```

It's worth noting I've tried to code this at least 4 different ways with and without DI, the only way it works is if I use AddSingleton, while this might not be an issue because this app is unlikely to ever be live, its a poor excuse not to do it right.

Comment: Scope is for each Request, not session.

Comment: Transient doesn't work either so where do I go from there?

Comment: If i recall, asp.net has a Session you can access. But it is not recommended to store big objects. The best is to store in a database, and make you request stateless - meaning getting and storing data for each request.

Comment: It seems a bit of waste to store this kind of stuff, which I intend to rewrite to have a limited number of entries and drop the oldest, to set up a database and the data access that comes with it. Its just storing a few short strings. Thanks though if all else fails I could do it that way.

Comment: Reading up on sessions more right now.

Comment: `It seems a bit of waste to store this kind of stuff, which I intend to rewrite to have a limited number of entries and drop the oldest, to set up a database and the data access that comes with it. Its just storing a few short strings.` `MemoryCache` or a singleton object with a `Dictionary` (keyed by the session) or Redis or a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe “scope” is by default per request  which would explain that each submit gets is own service.

“Doing stuff right” is of course to some extend a matter of opinion. But my opinion would clearly be that I would avoid server-side session to avoid problems with scaling to more than one instance. There are also ways to support shared state, but this is difficult. To me singletons are not a code smell either, but they have their own problems.

Your problem might be solved by storing whatever state you need in the browser either in a cookie or localStorage. Your service would then have request scope, but it would read user state from browser causing “user scope” for the data. (But don’t rely on browser state to persist and remember it is modifiable to the user.)

Comment: Thanks man, I have no idea how to do that yet (use cookies or local storage) but I guess thats another thing to learn :) My concern with singleton is that if something like this would be put in production all users would see the same history object.

Comment: You are welcome. Of course your concern about history is justified, but your service should in the sketched solution merely be a facade to reading state from the cookie. Or from a db if you need real persistence or require a large history.